# Django User table as Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, web

I'm a new user to Django and am just starting my first app, "myapp".

In my models.py for my app I have the following model:

```
class Subcalendar(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

But when I try running:

```
python manage.py sql myapp
```

I get an error stating:

```
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

Do I need to make my own model for User or is there another way of calling it in my model's foreign key field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need import the `User` model at the top of your file

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

so python can resolve the reference.